# When do we use ' before a value in Lisp?

Tags: lisp

I am following a tutorial on youtube online and I noticed that the teacher    used ' before a value. like this:

```
(defvar *randomStuff* 'stuff)
```

all help will be appreciated

Comment: Here is a good book for learning basic Lisp, you can even freely download a PDF version: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: It's the same as answer to: When do we use " on both sides of something in programming code? `'stuff` makes a interned symbol with "stuff" as name while `"stuff"` makes a string with "stuff" as content while `stuff` evaluates a variable named "stuff"